# How to make ZAP Proxy go to background?

Tags: macos, web, proxy, zap

I've a problem with ZAP Proxy that prevents it from letting other windows be displayed on top of it. That is every window gets displayed behind the ZAP Proxy main window; in order to view other windows, the ZAP Proxy main windows must be resized.

The problem is present on macOS Mojave (haven't tested it on other platforms).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the menu: "Tools / Options / Breakpoints" then uncheck the "ZAP always on top when break point hit". You should have been shown a popup dialog explaining this when it was first activated, but these things are easy to forget.

Comment: Thank you. I know it is off-topic, but why is the latest major release of ZAP dating back to 2017 :-) ?

Comment: ...because that's the latest major release.

Comment: If more people contributed we'd be able to do more and have more frequent releases ;)